# Detecting whether a point is above or below a polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I saw a lot of similar questions, but all regarding to the line and my problem is that I need to check whether the point is below or above a polynomial of degree 2, 3, 4 or 5. 
What I tried to do was just putting an $X_p$ (x from given point) into polynomial equation and check if its result is lower or greater than $Y_p$, but it's definitely not a correct way to do this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Why is it definitely not a correct way to do it like that?

Comment: Hm, I tried a few calculations and it seemed to my, that it works only for polynomial of 2nd degree, but if you say so, I'll believe you :), I will take a second glance on my calculations. Thanks, guys!

Comment: How else would you define being “above” or “below” the graph of the function?